# Combobox resets to first "blank" entry if cell on left is blank Error

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have 6 dependent ComboBoxes that I would like to be reset to blank when the cell next to it becomes blank. The code works fine as long as the main list is set on a value. However, if the main combo box is set at its default value, which gives the dependent boxes no value to select, the code gives me:

> Run-time error 308: Could not set the ListIndex Property. Invalid property value.

Also, when the sheet is first opened, I can not type anything into the cells being checked for `""` values.

I tried wrapping the code with another If statement but I must be doing something wrong because the code seems to run anyway.

Can someone take a look and tell me if you can see a problem please?

Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If cboShiftsList.Object.ListIndex > -1 Then
        If Range("I15") = "" Then
            cboDependentShiftList.Object.ListIndex = 0
        End If
        If Range("I16") = "" Then
            cboDependentShiftList1.Object.ListIndex = 0
        End If
        If Range("I17") = "" Then
            cboDependentShiftList2.Object.ListIndex = 0
        End If
        If Range("I18") = "" Then
            cboDependentShiftList3.Object.ListIndex = 0
        End If
        If Range("I19") = "" Then
            cboDependentShiftList4.Object.ListIndex = 0
        End If
        If Range("I20") = "" Then
            cboDependentShiftList5.Object.ListIndex = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I have this code in the `Workbook_Open` event:

```
'Populate combo box with Shifts categories.

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Staff Page")
Worksheets("Staff Page").cboShiftsList.Clear

For Each rng In ws.Range("ShiftSelectList")
    Worksheets("Staff Page").cboShiftsList.AddItem rng.Value
    Worksheets("Staff Page").cboShiftsList.Object.ListIndex = 0
Next rng
```

Here is a link to the file if anyone would like to take a look. I get the feeling I didn't share enough about the issue and maybe seeing the file will help. Thanks Again!

[ComboBox_Issues.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_L7FgWjFndDMFV6dVVhaHZLUWhwSzJLdWdTa1pDcGlldWtR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Isn't `cboDependentShiftList.ListIndex = -1` what you want?

Comment: Tried it, I am still getting the error with that. I should also mention that I have placed a code in the Sub Workbook Open event. I updated the original post to reflect it.

Comment: I can't see the problem in your code. It might be due to data validation or something.

Comment: Thanks for checking it! 
I'm going to try to move the workbook open event into a page open event and set it so it will only run the first time the page is opened. If you get any ideas, let me know!

Comment: I just uploaded the file if you want to take a look.

Comment: In my first comment I suggested `cboDependentShiftList.ListIndex = -1` but obviously I meant to do the same modification to **all** those lines in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` routine. did you try that?

Comment: I just tried it. The sheet works again but the list won't reset to default value when the cell is emptied. Do you have any ideas how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!!** 
I was able to use the suggestion from @A.S.H and changed the value I was checking in the Main combo box and now it works perfectly. 
Thanks @A.S.H! 
**Here's the final code:**

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If cboShiftsList.Object.ListIndex > 0 Then
    If Range("I15") = "" Then
    cboDependentShiftList.Object.ListIndex = -1
        End If
    If Range("I16") = "" Then
    cboDependentShiftList1.Object.ListIndex = -1
        End If
    If Range("I17") = "" Then
    cboDependentShiftList2.Object.ListIndex = -1
        End If
    If Range("I18") = "" Then
    cboDependentShiftList3.Object.ListIndex = -1
        End If
    If Range("I19") = "" Then
    cboDependentShiftList4.Object.ListIndex = -1
        End If
    If Range("I20") = "" Then
    cboDependentShiftList5.Object.ListIndex = -1
    End If
End If
End Sub
```